# Pesach Upcoming Event time frame

Tags: discussion, events

About that Pesach upcoming event I keep seeing in the sidebar... Five days from now is Tuesday, first day of Pesach. Shouldn't we extend it to thirteen days from now, for the end of Pesach? Make an identical event (read: same tags) labeled "end of Pesach"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already set to go through April 19, 2017. 4 days from now is just when it starts.